# Selecting all Columns which have not already been mentioned

Tags: sql, postgresql

First off: I am reverse engineering SQL queries and as a result I have a bunch of candidate queries, which all contain a designated 'entity' column in their SELECT clause.

The problem is: I want the entity column to be the first column of my result and let all the other columns follow, so basically I want something like this

```
SELECT A.entity, *
FROM A
...
```

...but **without the duplicate** entity column resulting from the *-operator.

EDIT: I also do not know all of the column names, generally only the entity column name is known.

Thanks for helping me

Comment: You can not. Don't be lazy, write all columns...

Comment: if you have a problem with duplicated column names, you can always do this:
SELECT A.entity as SUPERIDENTITY, *
FROM A

Comment: I don't always know all the column names, I generally only know the entity column.

Comment: you can script CREATE VIEW by select from info_schema.column by columnname='entity'. so you have views with all columns as were and enum renamed to enum_table_anme or something. It will take you 5 minutes and will add N views to schema...